# Array set to nil after an iteration

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a problem where an attribute turns to `nil` after an iteration:

```
NSMutableArray * lojas = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];    
for (int x = 0; x < lojaResultado.count; x++) {

            NSDictionary * listaAtributos = [lojaResultado objectAtIndex: x];
            Loja * loja = [[Loja alloc] init];
            NSMutableArray * produtosLista = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            [loja     setName: [listAtributos objectForKey: @"Loja"]];
            NSArray * produtosResultado  = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray: [listaAtributos objectForKey: @"Produtos"]];

            for(int y = 0; y < produtosResultado.count; y++){
                NSDictionary * produtoAtributos = [produtosResultado objectAtIndex:y];
                Produto * produto = [[Produto alloc] init];
                [produto                               setNome: [produtoAtributos objectForKey:@"Nome"]];
                getNumber =    [produtoAtributos objectForKey: @"Tipo"];
                [produto                            setTipo: [getNumber intValue]];
                getNumber =    [produtoAtributos objectForKey: @"Tamanho"];
                [produto                          setTamanho: [getNumber intValue]];
                [produtosLista addObject: produto];
            }

            loja.produtos = produtosLista;
            [lojas addObject: loja];
    }
```

During the iteration I can see, at the debug mode, that my objetc `loja` receive the correct name on the method `setName` and the correct list (`loja.produtos = produtosLista`).
After add the object `loja` into my array `lojas` I can see the correct object, but when the second iteration starts, the object at the first array position has its attribute `produtos` (array) setted to `nil`.
Has someone had this problem before? Or can someone say what I am doing wrong?

Loja `.h` file:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSString * name;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray * produtos;
```

Comment: Did you `alloc/init` the `lojas` variable?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense: "the object at the first array position has the array lojas setted to nil". And as rmaddy says, how do you know lojas isn't nil before you start?

Comment: Yes, I did. I can see the object loja in the array lojas after [lojas addObject: loja]

Comment: @MrH Sorry, I wanted to say the object 'loja' at the fisrt array (lojas) position has the array 'produtos' setted to nil. The variable 'lojas' alloc/init is on beginning method.

Comment: @JoshCaswell is the same variable. Typo - Edited

Comment: I'm confused and I think everybody else is, so its not lojas nor lojas[0] which is nil? Instead its produtos which is nil? If so then that is so not clear from your question.

Comment: @MrH I edited my question. It's the array `produtos`, attribute of `loja`, that turns to nil after the iteration.

Comment: Show your definition of loja, in particular how produtos is defined as a property.

Comment: @MrH added on question. In Loja .m is only (a)synthesize.

Comment: What is the object "tires" that is added to produtosLista? Should it be produto?

Comment: By the way, I have sometimes seen the debugger show the wrong values in arrays: usually fixed by an Xcode restart or a computer reboot.

Comment: P.S. where did tires come from?

Comment: @MichaelL - Never trust the debugger variable display.  Use NSLog or `po` in the console instead.

Comment: Yeah, where did `tires` come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw in your code that `[produtosLista addObject: tires];` but tires is not created in the method block, its seems like in second iteration `tires` is flushed out.

as your implementation its seems like you want to add product, can you try this code.

**Update:**

I updated the code snippet with using fast enumeration and removed `alloc/init` for array allocation and used autorelease concept.

```
NSMutableArray * lojas = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSDictionary *listaAtributos in lojaResultado) {
    Loja * loja = [[Loja alloc] init];
    [loja setName:[listAtributos objectForKey: @"Loja"]];

    NSMutableArray * produtosLista = [NSMutableArray array];
    for(NSDictionary * produtoAtributos in [listaAtributos objectForKey: @"Produtos"]){
        Produto * produto = [[Produto alloc] init];
        [produto setNome:[produtoAtributos objectForKey:@"Nome"]];
        [produto setTipo:[[produtoAtributos objectForKey: @"Tipo"] intValue]];
        [produto setTamanho:[[produtoAtributos objectForKey:@"Tamanho"] intValue]];
        [produtosLista addObject:produto];
    }

    [loja setProdutos:produtosLista];
    [lojas addObject: loja];
}
```

Comment: I changed my object `tires` to `produto` and the error still happens.

Comment: @Gian updated with some objective c concept, can you try with updated code and update your findings.